# Media Player showing always null on uri

Tags: android

i have problem with my media player can't understand that if problem is with my Uri or with media player.    I have tried with the following Uries..

```
    String media = Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/media/internal/audio/media/notifications/"+myTune+".mp3"
    Uri uri = Uri.Parse(media);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,uri);
```

Another One

```
    String media = Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/media/audio/notifications/+myTune+".mp3";
    Uri uri = Uri.Parse(media);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,uri);
```

And Third One

```
    String media = Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/media/internal/audio/media/notifications/"+myTune";
    Uri uri = Uri.Parse(media);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,uri);
```

But on all these media player is null i am getting myTune with from system notifications..Please Help me guys...

Comment: have you added permissions in AndroidManifest.xml...

Comment: i have not checked but i am still showing built in tunes in list with success and the myTune value i am getting from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have checked Requesting Permissions at Run Time
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Comment: i have not checked but i am still showing built in tunes in list with success and the myTune value i am getting from there

Answer (score 0):

Try hardcoding the path below first and then verify with your 'myTune'.
Also it would help to add what your myTune exaclty is.

Please verify that the file exists at that location and the path enterend is not wrong.

```
//String media = Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/media/internal/audio/media/notifications/"+myTune+".mp3"
//or ENTER FULL PATH MANUALLY TO TEST 
String media = Environment.getRootDirectory()+"/media/internal/audio/media/notifications/<yourtunenamehere>.mp3"
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(onPreparedListener);
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(media);
mediaPlayer.prepare();


private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener onPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
  mediaPlayer.start();
  }
};
```

Also add this permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```